# Decoding an Encrypted Message

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, rsa

I'm doing my own implementation of RSA algorithm in java.
So far i have it working, i want to be able to encrypt a message string eg. "hello"
its a very basic version not using any large numbers at the moment.

So I read in each letter gets its Ascii Code and endcode it.

But im having a problem trying to figure out a way to read in the sequence of numbers that it outputs.

say the sequence of numbers for hello encrypted is;
H    E   L   L   0
101 123 111,111,101 (these are just random picked numbers btw)

so say my message becomes 101123111111101

if im reading these numbers back how do i know which parts to decrypt? My first thought was to use some kind of delimter between the numbers eg.101,123,111,111,101

And parse them when read back in?
Or have i missed something?

Will this cause problems later if i change my public and private keys and the numbers become much larger and more random?

Comment: "Im doing my own implementation of RSA algorithm in java" - now why might that not be a good idea?

Comment: @MitchWheat - lol, what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: did you encrypt each character separately? that's wrong. it's weak and can be easily decrypted. for example, if you send a long list of the encrypted values, one can guess that H is always mapped to 101.

Comment: if you want to implement your own RSA, it should encrypt the whole message by considering it as a big number. However, there is a limit size for your message in RSA, e.g. messgae cannot be longer than 117 bytes for 1024bit key.

Comment: Sometimes people write code just to learn--doesn't need to be a Bouncy Castle competitor to be educational.

Comment: @Dave: and sometimes that 'learning' code gets into production. There are several things only experts should design, two of which are: random number generation and cryptography!

Comment: @MitchWheat Yep, I agree. Also not willing to throw someone under the bus for poking at it, though.

Comment: @MitchWheat its for a college asignment, at least i didnt come here looking for how to do the RSA Algorithm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if each code is exactly the same amount of numbers long then you can just split the content every so many characters. for example, you're using 0-9 for the last two digits and 1-9 for the first, that's 9 times 10 to the 2'nd power and has 900 possibilities. So lets say you decide that everything is assigned a unique 3 numbers.

example A=171, B=182, C=193, D=204, E=215 etc.

Then you use sub-strings when reading the file. and then convert each back to their corresponding value. but what you should do to make it harder to decrypt, is use different values for two letters/numbers at a time

HELLO :
HE : 10291
LL : 19024
0  : 11958

etc. That will make it much harder to decrypt, exponentially harder, and you can keep doing that for 3, 4, 5, 6 and more at a time.

Comment: your math is little off. There are ten decimal digits, 0-9; hence the word 'decimal'. 3 decimal digits may encode 1000 different values, etc.

Comment: You have 3 times that 0-9 can appear, which means you have 10 to the third power, 10*10*10. I said 9*9*9 because in java sometimes working with 002 for example, java will shorten it to 2, and you loose two 0's. If you then put that all in a message then anything after that is shifted two digits left, therefore the words would get mixed up.

A string would fix this, but for most purposes, you'd probably want to use an int, because then you can come up with an algorithm for the value instead of having to like store each one. And now that I think about it, it should be 9*10*10 or 900. Thank you